Homeomorphy of the outer face in plane graphs
Assume $G := (V,E)$ is a plane graph and $G$ is connected. A lemma states that every face in the embedding of $G$ is homeomorphic to an open disc because this graph is connected. I see that in the case that $G$ has a cycle, but if $G$ is for example a tree, then the embedding has one face according to Euler's formula, the outer face.
Problem is, I don't see how that face is homeomorphic to an open disc.
You see I know almost nothing about topology, and when I use the "simple" definition of homeomorphism by stretching the plane, then I still can't see how I can morph the plane or the graph so that the face looks (or behaves) like an open disc.
Could it be that I just misread the lemma and the outer face is not meant, or am I just blind and don't see how it holds true for the outer face?

How are the graphs embedded? If the graph is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, the outer faces are never homeomorphic to an open disk. If the graph is embedded on a sphere, then this is true, but there is no notion of outer faces.
